# touchEnded и SKAction

Tags: ios, swift, spritekit

Начал только постигать *Swift* и *SpriteKit*. Столкнулся с проблемой.

Есть объект, который двигается по нажатию в указанную точку (*В*) и возвращается в начальную точку (*А*). Реализуется все это в методе, в который передаётся координата, куда перемещать объект (*В*), в самом методе запоминается начальная позиция объекта (*А*) и реализуется движение из точки *А* в *В* с помощью `SKAction.moveTo` и `SKAction.sequence`. Вызывается метод в `touchEnded` на сцене.

Вопрос: как реализовать так, чтобы по нажатию объект переместился из *А* в *В* и вернулся, и лишь затем мог двигаться в новую точку?

В данный момент, если объект двигается и пользователь нажимает на экран, объект меняет траекторию на новую.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте объекту **state** и проработайте механизм его изменения, например из состояния **Moving** нельзя перейти в состояние **Jump**, только из **Idle**.

Вот тут эта тема хорошо рассмотрена и указан правильный дизайн классов, даже если вы не используете Xcode 7 beta, это отлично подходит как пример: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=608

даже если вы элементарно добавите 2 состояния **Ready** и **PerformingAction** уже все будет проще

Comment: Решил проблему обработав в touchEnded через метод объекта .hasActions(). На сколько универсально не знаю))

Comment: @electromind в любом случае видео очень полезное для любого, кто использует SpriteKit